# $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{2^{2}}+\frac{3}{2^{3}}+\frac{4}{2^{4}}...$ is convergent or divergent?

Tags: convergence-divergence

$$\lim_{n \to \infty } \frac{n}{2^{n}}$$

$$ \text{(using L'Hopitals rule)}$$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty } \frac{1}{n2^{n-1}}$$

$$\frac{1}{\infty }=0$$

$\therefore $ Convergent?

Is this the correct solution?

Comment: Of course not. $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n}$ is divergent, even if $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{1}{n}=0$.

Comment: No, this is not correct. Observe that $\lim a_n$ is something different than $\lim\sum a_n$. And $[2^x]'=\ln 2\cdot 2^x\neq x\cdot 2^{x-1}$

Comment: Using L'Hospital's rule for a sequence rather than a function is an abomination! As others have pointed out, this is a case for the ratio test.

Comment: @Lord you can do that some times, by example if the extension of some $f(n)$ to $\Bbb R$ is strictly monotone then it holds that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)=\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$$ and you can use L'Hôpital rule in the RHS to find the limit. For example in this case the use of L'Hôpital rule is possible, but ofc not directly over $f(n)$ if not over it monotone extension to $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Note that the title asks something entirely different than the problem addressed in the body of the Question.

Comment: NO? The title asks whether it is convergent or divergent, and the body just states my approach which could be right or wrong. So the question in the title stands!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It is true that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{2^n}=0$, but it doesn't follow that the series is convergent.

To show that it is convergent, try using the ratio test.

Comment: Sorry, can you elaborate on the ratio test? Thanks so much!

Comment: @Idkwoman do you know what ratio test is?  Did you apply it?

Comment: Ratio test: if $\big|\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\big|<1$, the series converges. If it is $>1$, the series does not converge. If the limit doesn't exist, or is $1$ or $-1$, the test is inconclusive.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** try comparing to a series if noting $\frac{n}{2^n}<1$

---

or you can compare to the integral $$\int_{}^\infty \frac{x}{2^x}dx$$

which you can derive with for example integration by parts.

Comment: How does this help?  I think it's too vague.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt:; You are right, I added a better one.

Answer (score 2):

This is incorrect. In general, if $\sum a_n$ converges, then $a_n \to 0$. However, the converse does not hold. Thus you should find another way. Observe that
$$
n < \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^n
$$
for all natural $n$. Then $0< \frac{n}{2^n} < \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^n$ for all $n$. Since $\sum \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^n$ converges, $\sum \frac{n}{2^n}$ converges by the comparison test.

In fact, you can find
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{2^n}=2.
$$